# Issue with document.execCommand in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using a html editor and wanted to extend feature to insert html controls at cursor position.

The code i am using is:

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<input type=\"text\">")
```

This code works fine Chrome and FF but have issue in IE. It simply doesn't work and throws "invalid argument" error. I have tried the following code:

```
if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
     range = document.selection.createRange();
     range.collapse(false);
     range.pasteHTML(value);
}
```

but the textbox add to top of the document and not inside the html editor.

I need help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing and matching IE and Modern browser standards in that method. I'm not sure it works the way you think it does. Try a little console.log() for firefox or alert() to see which browsers actually enter that method :)

There is no document.selection in Firefox. It's window.getSelection() instead:

Try playing around with the following. Should work in both browsers

```
if (document.createRange) { // "Standards" :)
    var selection = window.getSelection();

    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        selRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var node = document.createTextNode(stringValue);
        selRange.insertNode(node);
        selRange.setStartAfter(node);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(selRange);
    }

} else if (document.selection) { // fallback for IE6-8
    selRange = document.selection.createRange();

    selRange.select();
    selRange.pasteHTML(stringValue);
}
```

If you encapsulate that in a method and pass "stringValue" you can insert text anywhere.

Hope that helps!